# Height 100% not working on children inside parent div with min-height : 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to expand children height inside a parent div with min-height of 100%, i want to expand wrapper's height according to the content inside it, if i set min-height to 100%, wrapper expands according to the content, but sidebar and sidebar-tanks collapse to the height of their content, i want them to be around 98% of the total height of the parent wrapper.

If i set height : 100% to parent wrapper, and height : 98% to children sidebar and sidebar-tank, they expand, but wrapper is not expanding according to the content inside content div, wrapper only expands upto the height of the browser and won't display overflowed content.

**HTML :**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="client-dasboard">

            <div class="sidebar">

            </div>

            <div class="sidebar-tanks">

            </div>

            <div class="content>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**SCSS :**

```
body{
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    height:100%;

    .wrapper{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 1168px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        background: #ececec;

        .sidebar,
        .sidebar-tanks{
            height: 98%;
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }

        .content{
            min-height: 100%;
            height:auto;
        }
    }  
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: No it's so-called "SASS".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
.sidebar,
.sidebar-tanks {
    height: 98%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Append an element to sidebar's parent with clear:both CSS property, and add float: right (or left) to content. It may help you.

But...

If you want to expand children height inside its parent div, try this technique: [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
It's very similar what you have to do. Here is another good article about [normalizing flexbox bugs](http://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/). It's very useful and easy to use.

I hope this will help you  :)